# How to add the single element in xml with the help of xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to add the single xml element with closing tags in xml with the help of xsl stylesheet.

here the below is  my xml.

```
 <Checkpax xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
    <customerLevel>
        <customerDetails>
            <paxDetails>
                <surname>MUKHERJEE</surname>
                <type>A</type>
                <gender>M</gender>
            </paxDetails>
            <otherPaxDetails>
                <givenName>JOY</givenName>
                <title>MR</title>
                <age>11</age>
            </otherPaxDetails>
            <otherPaxDetails>
                <title>MR</title>
            </otherPaxDetails>
        </customerDetails>
        <staffDetails>
            <staffInfo/>
            <staffCategoryInfo>
                <attributeDetails>
                    <attributeType>NA</attributeType>
                </attributeDetails>
            </staffCategoryInfo>
        </staffDetails>
        <productLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>abc</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
        </productLevel>
        <CustomerLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>cde</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
        </CustomerLevel>
    </customerLevel>
</Checkpax>
```

My XSL stylehseet:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://xml.api.com/test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:productLevel/ns0:legLevel/ns0:legLevelIndicator/ns0:statusDetails">
        <statusInformation xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </statusInformation>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:productLevel/legLevel">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <dumTXFSep/>
        <dummySegmentJan />
        <dumTktFeb />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:productLevel">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <dummyRootOne />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here i tried to add the dumTXFSep,dummySegmentJan and dumTktFeb elements before the product level tag end.dummyRootOne element to be added before the CustomerLevel tag end.dummyRoottwo should be added at the end of the product level.LeglevelInfo should be added inside the productLevel/legLevel tag.

the below is my expected xml.

```
  <Checkpax xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
    <customerLevel>
        <customerDetails>
            <paxDetails>
                <surname>MUKHERJEE</surname>
                <type>A</type>
                <gender>M</gender>
            </paxDetails>
            <otherPaxDetails>
                <givenName>JOY</givenName>
                <title>MR</title>
                <age>11</age>
            </otherPaxDetails>
            <otherPaxDetails>
                <title>MR</title>
            </otherPaxDetails>
        </customerDetails>
        <staffDetails>
            <staffInfo/>
            <staffCategoryInfo>
                <attributeDetails>
                    <attributeType>NA</attributeType>
                </attributeDetails>
            </staffCategoryInfo>
        </staffDetails>
        <productLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <LeglevelInfo/>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>abc</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
        </productLevel>
        <dummyRoottwo/>
        <CustomerLevel>
            <legLevel>
                <legLevelIndicator>
                    <statusDetails>
                        <indicator>cde</indicator>
                        <action>1</action>
                    </statusDetails>
                </legLevelIndicator>
            </legLevel>
            <dumTXFSep/>
            <dummySegmentJan />
            <dumTktFeb />
        </CustomerLevel>
        <dummyRootOne />
    </customerLevel>
</Checkpax>
```

please suggest the xsl and kindly help me is there any tools to generate the xsl by mapping the two xml elements or any good resource for learning.

Comment: What isn't working? Show the actual output and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: *How to add the single xml element with closing tags in xml*...what does this mean? Add mathematically or insert new node? What single element? And all elements in well-formed XML has closing tags.

Comment: <dummyRootOne /> this is the one i am calling as single element.i am not familiar with the xml,so i dont know the proper term.@Parfait

Comment: I tried to add the dummyRoottwo,dummyRootOne  like these element ,but its not getting added with the above xsl.already i have posted the actual xml ansd expected xml with xsl. @Jim Garrison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general structure of your XSLT is good, with the XSLT identity template and overriding templates for elements you wish to change. The problem is with a couple of you templates. Firstly with this one...

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:productLevel">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <dummyRootOne />
</xsl:template>
```

The main problem here is your use of `xsl:copy-of`. This will copy the current element entirely, but will not select any templates for any of the child nodes. This means the other templates in your XSLT will not be matched against the descendant nodes. You should use `xsl:apply-templates` here.

Also note you are adding `dummyRootOne` with no namespace, but you probably want to add it in the same namespace as your XML. i.e. do `<dummyRootOne  xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test" />`. Alternatively you can define a default namespace on your `xsl:stylesheet` element to cover this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test"
```

The second problem (once the first one is fixed) is with this template

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:productLevel/legLevel">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <dumTXFSep/>
    <dummySegmentJan />
    <dumTktFeb />
</xsl:template>
```

The problem here (apart from the use of `xsl:copy-of`) is that you have missed the `ns0` prefix from `legLevel` so it is looking for an element in no namespace, and won't match the one in your XML which is in a namespace. Your question also suggests you want to match the element under `customerLevel` too.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test"
    xmlns:ns0="http://xml.api.com/test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:productLevel/ns0:legLevel/ns0:legLevelIndicator">
        <LeglevelInfo />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:productLevel/ns0:legLevel/ns0:legLevelIndicator/ns0:statusDetails">
        <statusInformation xmlns="http://xml.api.com/test">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </statusInformation>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:CustomerLevel/ns0:legLevel">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <dumTXFSep/>
        <dummySegmentJan />
        <dumTktFeb />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:customerLevel/ns0:productLevel">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <dummyRootOne />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.its working fine.but how to add the element <LeglevelInfo/>  or <Status>Checked-Out</Status> inside the tag productLevel/legLevel @Tim C

Comment: I've added a template to handle adding a `<LegLevelInfo />` element. I will leave adding `<Status>Checked-Out</Status>` as a exercise for you, not least because it is not mentioned in your original question. Thanks!

Comment: yes giving all the work is not good.thanks tim.i will try and update here@Tim C

Comment: replaced the <LegLevelInfo /> and added the <Status>Checked-Out</Status> its worked super.